# Hibernate Mapping not working in offline mode

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We are going through Disaster Recovery exercise and several Hibernate+Spring applications are not starting with following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:214)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByName(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1029)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:977)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
                ... 55 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:541)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:638)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
                ... 67 more
**Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd Nested exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd**
                at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:532)
                ... 71 more
```

The hbm mapping XML file has

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Searching on SO and Hibernate forums the fix looks like we need to make DTD in the doctype to SYSTEM so it reads from local system instead of public dtd hosted on sourceforge.net

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

But with this Hibernate is looking for the file on appserver root folder

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:541)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:638)
                at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
                ... 72 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: C:\IBMSOA\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrvWSFP01\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified.) Nested exception: C:\IBMSOA\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrvWSFP01\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified.)
                at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:532)
                ... 76 more
```

How should the SYSTEM DTD reference be specified so Hibernate reads DTD from hibernate.jar instead of looking for it in the file system?

Comment: What happened to the answer which was posted?

Comment: This answer was "*deleted by owner*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at hibernate source for DTDEntityResolver http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.1.GA/org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver.java#DTDEntityResolver the below worked for us

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Yay for open source!

Answer (score 1):

download the dtd file and use it locally it will work

Answer (score 0):

http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"

download  this file and use it locally

same for the config file